# Storing users IP address in a DB in order to compare it later on

Tags: reactjs, typescript, postgresql, express

I'm quite new to React and after doing a Todo web app I've tried creating my first fullstack web app. 
The app sends a request upon entering an Email and pressing a button that should send the users mail to a DB and get his IP which would also be stored into the same DB. This would later be used to check if the user had already done something on the site (After entering the email the client-s sent to the next page) and disallow the user to proceed if either the email or IP are already stored in the DB. What would be the best way to both grab the IP upon entering the email and what would be the best approach in regards of storing it into a DB? (Should I even store it there is there a better alternative).
I'm writing my code with Typescriptx and using Express for my backend & postgres for my DB. 
 
**TLDR: How to get the clients IP onClick / upon recieveing a request from them and store it in a database to later compare when the user sends the same request again**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, you can get the IP address from the incoming request. That's the right way to do this (but see below: I think you probably don't want to do this).

In express, this is available via `req.socket.remoteAddress`. If you're behind some kind of reverse proxy like a CDN then this will give you the CDN's IP, not the real user, but all modern proxies will include the original IP in a request header such as `X-Forwarded-For` to work around this. You can get the IP from there instead, if that's present. You'll need to look at the docs for your specific infrastructure to check the header they use in this case.

---

That said, it sounds like you're trying to ensure each user can do exactly one thing, so that after sending an email nothing else is allowed. Is that right?

If that's the case, limiting it by IP address isn't a great solution. Two reasons:

- Many users share an IP address, e.g. many many mobile users who are behind [CGNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), everybody sharing an office/home, etc etc
- At the same time, many users have multiple IP addresses, e.g. offices that use multiple internet connections in parallel for failover or performance, or people taking their computer from their home to a cafe, etc etc.

In both cases, you'll end up blocking or allowing large numbers of users incorrectly. Typically this kind of thing is done with cookies/local storage on the client side instead, which lets you block this individual user's browser. That will work correctly in environments with shared IPs and environments with multiple IPs.

A client-side approach is not 100% secure, since a technical user could easily clear their cookies to avoid this. If you need a hard guarantee though then neither option would work (it's easy to change your IP too: go sit in the coffee shop outside, or use your phone as a hotspot). In that case, you need to tie the user to something they can't as easily change, maybe an email address, credit card, or even legal ID if you're seriously trying to lock this down hard.

I wouldn't bother: for most web app, client-side storage is usually the right choice.